# Django - Development server all ports forbidden

Tags: django

I am get a little crazy with Django development server

Since yesterday, i got the following message:

```
0 errors found January 17, 2014 - 17:49:31 
Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'applibs.settings' 
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
Quit the server with CONTROL-C. 
Error: You don't have permission to access that port.
```

And this, independently from the port i use...i tried with 8081, 8082 and so on.

I must have changed something but i can't figure out what exactly

Any help would be welcomed

thanks

EDIT: Reason Found!

I finally understand the reason for such problem and it has nothing to do with the ports as it initially seems to be.

Indeed, i am initiating a logger in Wsgi.py as shown below

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s \t %(name)s \t %(levelname)s \t %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',filename=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'applibs.log'))
```

All traces are logged in a file called applibs.log

If the file does not exist, it is automatically created.

If i run the development server, the file will be created with the current user as owner and group.

If i run a production server (ie. apache), the file will be created with the apache user (www-data) as owner and group.

In any case, the file is created with write access only to the user.

So what happened?

I ran the application on a production server. The file was created with user www-data. 
Then when i tried to run the application in development server, the application was trying to access the same file (which has already been created) with the current user and so the access is refused.

Et voila :)

Comment: This means, as the message says, the user you are running the django development server don't have permission to access that port. Try running it with root user.

Comment: What about port `12345`? Does it work with that one?

Comment: As Santosh said, it looks like a files/folder permission error. You could chmod 775 the django folder to give your user permissions

Comment: @Paulo: same problem with 12345 @Santosh/Joe: it is working with the root user but as i am using PyDev it is not convenient to use such root user.Moreover, it was working a day ago. That is what is confusing me